# Data binding not updating

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, data-binding

I have a collection of entities   stored in a List of Customers, a combobox bound to that list and an object "SelectedCustomer" that gets the  selected  customer in the combobox , but here s the problem i have a textbox bound to that object   ,which not updating whenever i store in that object a new element from the collection

Here s my code

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window 
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();


        using (var context = new Entities())
        {

            Customers = context.PERFCONTENEUR.ToList();

            CustomersCombo.SelectedItem = Customers[0];

        }




        DataContext = this;

    }

    public List<PERFCONTENEUR> Customers { get; set; }
    public PERFCONTENEUR SelectedCustomer { get; set; }


    private void move(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        DragMove();



    }


    private void main1_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {


    }

    private void CustomersCombo_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        SelectedCustomer = CustomersCombo.SelectedItem as PERFCONTENEUR;





    }

    private void CustomersCombo_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

Here s  my XAML

```
 <TextBox Text="{Binding SelectedCustomer.ID}"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="548,49,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120"/>
    <ComboBox  x:Name="CustomersCombo"
               ItemsSource="{Binding Customers}"
               DisplayMemberPath="CLIENT"
               SelectedValuePath="ID"

               HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="421,54,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" SelectionChanged="CustomersCombo_SelectionChanged" />
```

And here s my implementation of the Interface INotifyPropertyChanged in the Perfconteneur Class which is the type of the SelectedCustomer object

public partial class PERFCONTENEUR:INotifyPropertyChanged

```
{   public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;


    private string _CLIENT;



    public decimal ID { get; set; }
    public Nullable<decimal> TAILLE { get; set; }
    public string CLIENT
    {
        get { return _CLIENT; }
        set
        {
            if (value != _CLIENT)
            {
                _CLIENT = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("CLIENT");

            }
        }
    }



    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(String info)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(info));
        }
    }
    public string D_ARRIVEE { get; set; }

    public virtual PERFREPARATION PERFREPARATION { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make you SelectedCostumer property notify the UI when this later change; add the INPC implemetation to your MainWindow

```
private PERFCONTENEUR _selectedCustomer;
    public PERFCONTENEUR SelectedCustomer
    {
        get { return _selectedCustomer; }
        set
        {
            if (value != _selectedCustomer)
            {
                _selectedCustomer = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("SelectedCustomer");

            }
        }
    }
```

I don't want to comment more about the conventions violation, try to adopt the common coding conventions because it will be much easier for other programmers to understand your code

Comment: Thank you so much , that did the work  . It's clear that i m new to c# and WPF